# Trouble with a PHP Calendar

Tags: php, css

So I have made a calendar using a php class and it works fine except when the first day of the month lands on a Saturday (two examples being February 1, 2020 or August 1, 2020). I believe the issue is in the PHP class, but I will include the CSS, along with a couple screenshots of what is happening.

PHP

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Calendar{

    private $month;
    private $year;
    private $days_of_week;
    private $num_days;
    private $date_info;
    private $day_of_week;

    public function __construct($month, $year, $days_of_week = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat')){

       // server info would be here.

        require_once(CONN_DB);
        require_once(SESH);

        $this->month = $month;
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->days_of_week = $days_of_week;
        $this->num_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this->month, $this->year);
        $this->date_info = getdate(strtotime('first day of', mktime(0,0,0,$this->month,1,$this->year)));
        $this->day_of_week = $this->date_info['wday'];          

    }

    public function show($conn){
        $output = '<div class="calRow">';

        foreach($this->days_of_week as $day){

            $output .= '<div class="calCol-1 header">'.$day.'</div>';

        }

        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="calRow dayRow">';

        if($this->day_of_week > 0){

            $output .= '<div class="calCol-'.$this->day_of_week.' empty"></div>';

        }
        //This is where I think the issue is...
        $current_day = 1;

        while($current_day <= $this->num_days){

            if($this->day_of_week == 7){
                $this->day_of_week = 0;
                $output .= '</div><div class="calRow dayRow">';
            }

            $day_date = str_pad($current_day,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $mnth_w_zero = str_pad($this->month,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $event_date = $this->year . '-' . $mnth_w_zero . '-' . $day_date;

            $output .= '<div class="calCol-1 day">';

                $output .= '<div class="date">'.$day_date.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="slots" id="'.$event_date.'"></div>';

            $output .= '</div>';

            $current_day++;
            $this->day_of_week++;
        }

        // bottom of issue spot...

        if($this->day_of_week != 7){
            $remaining_days = 7 - $this->day_of_week;
            $output .= '<div class="calCol-'.$remaining_days.' empty"></div>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';

        echo $output;
    }

}
```

CSS

```css
.cal_selector {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#calendar_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  border-right: 1px solid var(--mainnav-background-color);
}

.dayRow {
  height: 15.8%;
}

div.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--mainnav-background-color);
}

div.empty {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

div.day {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

div.date {
  padding: 2px;
}

span.event {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.spread {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.eventSlot {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.eventSlot:hover .infopane {
  display: block;
}

.infopane {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: var(--mainnav-background-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--main-front-color);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.optionPane {
  text-align: center;
}

.calOpts {
  padding: 2px;
}

.calCol-1 {
  width: 14.28%;
}

.calCol-2 {
  width: 28.57%;
}

.calCol-3 {
  width: 42.86%;
}

.calCol-4 {
  width: 57.15%;
}

.calCol-5 {
  width: 71.44%;
}

.calCol-6 {
  width: 85.73%;
}

.calCol-7 {
  width: 99.99%;
}

[class*="calCol-"] {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--mainnav-background-color);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.calRow {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--mainnav-background-color);
}

.calRow::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Top PHP on myCalendar.php (calls myCalendar_class.php)

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   //server info here

    require_once(CONN_DB);
    require_once(SESH);
    require_once(CALENDAR_CLASS);

?>
```

HTML on myCalendar.php

```html
<script src="Scripts/Calendar/scripts_calendar.js"></script>

<span class="pageTitle">My Calendar</span>

<div class="cal_selector">

  <div class="cal_selector_center">
    <select id="month_select" name="month_select" style="width:150px">
      <option value='1'>January</option>
      <option value='2'>February</option>
      <option value='3'>March</option>
      <option value='4'>April</option>
      <option value='5'>May</option>
      <option value='6'>June</option>
      <option value='7'>July</option>
      <option value='8'>August</option>
      <option value='9'>September</option>
      <option value='10'>October</option>
      <option value='11'>November</option>
      <option value='12'>December</option>
    </select>

    <select id='year_select' name="year_select" style="width:75px;">

      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
      <option value="2021">2021</option>
      <option value="2022">2022</option>
      <option value="2023">2023</option>
      <option value="2024">2024</option>
      <option value="2025">2025</option>

    </select>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="calendar_div"></div>
```

JQuery

```js
function create_event_slots() {

  $('.slots').each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var d = new Date(id + 'T01:00:00');
    var ms = d.getTime();
    var div = "";

    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

      div += '<div class="eventSlot" id="' + ms + '_' + i + '"></div>';

    }

    $(this).html(div);

  });

}

function change_calendar(mnth, year) {

  var str = 'month=' + mnth + '&year=' + year;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: str,
    url: 'Functions/load_calendar.php',
    success: function(result) {

      $('#calendar_div').html(result);
      create_event_slots();
      update_events(mnth, year);
    }

  });



}

function set_selects_to_current_month() {

  var d = new Date();

  var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = d.getFullYear();

  var m_sel = $('#month_select');
  var y_sel = $('#year_select');

  m_sel.val(m);
  y_sel.val(y);

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  set_selects_to_current_month();

  change_calendar($('#month_select').val(), $('#year_select').val());

  $('#month_select').change(function() {
    change_calendar($(this).val(), $('#year_select').val());
  });

  $('#year_select').change(function() {
    change_calendar($('#month_select').val(), $(this).val());
  });

});
```

Correct Result

[a correctly rendered calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4awJb.jpg)

Incorrect result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm7p6.jpg)

Comment: Have you done any debugging to try to narrow down where the problem might be?

Comment: Could you please provide the PHP code that's calling the `Calendar` constructor? Specifically for Feb 2020.  It would also be nice to see the rendered HTML the corresponds to that (images are nice, but HTML is better)

Comment: I have updated the post to include more of the code, including the jquery that is used. I didn't include the php sql queries because they don't have anything to do with the issue. I am pretty sure the issue is in the class.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else. I am an amateur at this for sure.

Comment: When I look in firefox's inspector, the space that Feb 1 should occupy doesn't highlight as it should. It hightlights with it's parent, but doesn't highlight like a sibling would if that makes any sense.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is returned by the call to `Functions/load_calendar.php?month=2&year=2020`?  You can either load that directly in your browser or view the response of the ajax call in your browser's network inspector.  I probably won't be able to take a look until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the CSS.

New CSS snippet

```css
.calCol-1 {
  width: 14.27%;
}

.calCol-2 {
  width: 28.56%;
}

.calCol-3 {
  width: 42.85%;
}

.calCol-4 {
  width: 57.14%;
}

.calCol-5 {
  width: 71.43%;
}

.calCol-6 {
  width: 85.72%;
}

.calCol-7 {
  width: 99.98%;
}
```

Old CSS Snippet

```css
.calCol-1 {
  width: 14.28%;
}

.calCol-2 {
  width: 28.57%;
}

.calCol-3 {
  width: 42.86%;
}

.calCol-4 {
  width: 57.15%;
}

.calCol-5 {
  width: 71.44%;
}

.calCol-6 {
  width: 85.73%;
}

.calCol-7 {
  width: 99.99%;
}
```

Essentially, for whatever reason in this situation the container was .01 percent too big to fit in the appropriate row.